# How to remove componet/k2/item/ from k2's urls?

Tags: joomla3.0

i use k2 and joomla 3.2 to create my website. now i want to remove url of component k2 from my url website. please help me

example:
http://www.mywebsite.com/component/k2/item/article

to 
http://www.mywebsite.com/article

Could anyone tell me how to do?please help.
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Try looking under the K2 Parameters- Advanced Settings- Advanced SEF Settings under the prefix for category URL.